# Can we copy recovery usb files to another recovery usb as bootable

Tags: windows-10, boot, data-recovery, bootable-media, hard-drive-recovery

I am using **HP 15-DK0045TX** Gaming Laptop which has **Windows 10 Home**.
I created a system recovery USB drive by using the "**Recovery drive**" application inside Windows 10. My doubt is, can we boot from another USB by copy files from the first USB to the second USB drive after making the second USB as a bootable by following "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-essentials/install/create-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive".

My intention is, I just want to format and use the bootable USB as normal after copy the files into a **desktop**. And if any crash occurs to my laptop I need to create a bootable USB by following the above-mentioned link and copy the recovery files from my **desktop** and install the recovery to my laptop. So we don't want to waste a USB drive by keeping a recovery all the time. What're your thoughts?

***Common doubts about recovery who visit this question:***

**1)** If we create a recovery by using the "Recovery drive" application, will it save the installed apps and os settings? Or it just saves the initial state of the laptop at the time it bought?

**2)** After install recovery, will it wipe out the entire c drive or just update the windows folder inside c drive?

**3)** Difference between recovery installation and fresh installation?

Comment: A recovery drive (RD)  is Not a backup solution, all it is good for is if your W10 no longer boots or loads, then you boot off of the RD to gain access to some repair tools, if you choose to include system files during the creation of the RD, then you can clean install W10

Comment: There is no windows 10 cds or iso file come with my laptop. So if my windows permanently crashed, the ultimate solution will be download Windows 10 from Microsoft website and install the drivers downloaded from hp website.Is it?

Comment: Yes,,,,, @KIRAN